# error while importing a library in a program

Tags: python

I tried to write a program but when I try to import my library it shows the following error.

```
def isprime(a):
    for i in range(2,a):
        if(a%i==0):
            return False
            break
    else:
            return True

def fact(a):
    f=1
    i=a+1
    for i in range(1,i):
        f=f*i
        return f

def sum(a):
    f=0
    i=a+1
    for i in range(1,i):
        f=f+i
        return f

def sub(a,b):
    z=a+b
    return f

def add(a,b):
    z=a-b
    return f
```

I saved the above program as addon1

When I try to call that program

```
import addon1.py as re
print('Choices')
print(['1-to find it is a prime no'],['2-Find factorial'],['3'])... 
# not completed yet
```

It's showing an error at the first line itself.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Revanth's\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import addon1.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'addon1.py'; 'addon1' is not a package.
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You are sure that addon1.py is the name of the first program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave off the file extension, it should work.

> import addon1 as re